# AndEngine player, background and camera

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing a 2D shooter using AndEngine. At the moment I'm trying to make the camera follow the player. As I've understood the common approach is to use the `SmoothCamera` zooming it and setting the chased entity. The problem is that the camera follows the player WITH background moving also (`RepeatingSpriteBackground`), so it looks like the player doesn't move at all though the actual position changes. So I don't really get how to make the camera follow the player and have the background not moving. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

've solved the problem by setting the background with attachSprite Scene's method, scaling it and using BoundCamera.God bless you.